Process.Start() method not opening notepad.exe application
I am coding in C#. Currently attempting to run the notepad executable from my universal WPF form targeted for Windows 10 (Visual Studio 2022). I want to run the Process.start("notepad.exe") however am having difficulty troubleshooting. It does not appear in task manager and does not launch the application. The code is not returning or throwing any exceptions and appears to be closing by itself when viewed in process monitor. I am rather new to coding and may have made some significant oversights that I just am not seeing. Any help in this matter is much appreciated. The code for the app is located below:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    ///
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

        private Process notePad = new Process();

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();


            notePad.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\notepad.exe";

            if (! System.IO.File.Exists(notePad.StartInfo.FileName))
            {

                Debug.WriteLine("FILE DOES NOT EXIST");

            }


            
            try
            {

                notePad.Start();
                notePad.WaitForExit();
                Debug.WriteLine("NOTEPAD IS RUNNING");

            }
            
            catch 
            {

                Debug.WriteLine("EXCEPTION THROWN");
            
            
            }
            


            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            
            if(notePad.HasExited == true)
            {

                Debug.WriteLine("NOTEPAD HAS EXITED");

            }
            else
            {

                Debug.WriteLine("UNKNOWN VALUE RETURNED");

            }
            

        }
    }
}



I have elevated visual studio to administrator in case there have been privilege issues.
I have attempted to manually enable all access privileges to notepad.exe
I have validated the file path exists.
I had disabled malware checker to temporarily investigate.
I have suspended the thread to allow the "Process.HasExited" property to be evaluated.
I have attempted to use the "Process.WaitForExit" property however it has had no effect.

